# Solving non linear equations where equations are equals in python

Tags: python, math, equation

I wonder and tried to google it, but I am not sure what to google it, how to solve linear equations where equations are equal between each other. I am able to write a specific algorithm for two equations but not dynamically for N equations. I will show the example of three (how my equations approximately looks like):

[image]

C1, C2, C3, X - are unknows, but I do not need to know result of X.

It can be interpreted like this (last equation C1 + C2 + C3 = 1 is not integrated here):

[image]

Please, don't try to solve this, I am not sure if these equations have results. I just randomly typed coefficients. But this is how my equations can looks like. Only with different coefficients. Ideally in python, but I will be happy if I know how to do it in maths with matrixes. I tried to calculated it with only two unknows and I have got quadratic equation in the end so with three unknowns there will be cubic in the end. With N unknows there will be polynomial equation with degree N. Also, I have to say, it do not have to be with 100% accuracy. I am not sure if its help somehow or not.

Comment: Hmm I don't think so it can be done with polynomial with degree N on a paper. So, I would like to know how to do it programmatically. But its also probably a math question I would say.

Comment: Is X on the right-hand side known or are you trying to find that too?  In order to find a solution for the N equation, you have to find the inverse matrix. Do you know how to find the inverse matrix?

Comment: Its also unknown but I dont need to know a result for it in the end. So I decided to left X alone on right side and that is why I am able to make all of them equal.

Comment: @enke I am not sure. But I don't thinks so. If you are right, try to explain yourself little bit more. Please.

Comment: Aren't these not linear equations? A 3-variable linear equation should have a form `ax + by + cz = d`, it's not obvious to me that these equations have that because of the variables on the right side. Beyond that, I think you should find a linear algebra solution that fits your problem and then worry about turning that into code.

Comment: @munir.aygun Yes I know how to find inverse matrix but when I have matrix for system of equations, but here, when I have on right side multiplication of unknowns, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh I changed the title, thanks.

Comment: I google something about solving linear equation iteratively. But I am not sure if I can apply that method on this.

Comment: You are searching for a mathematical method. Perhaps [mathematics.se] would be a better place to ask. Stack Overflow would be a better place to ask how to code a known solution method.

Comment: @JohnColeman I though, someone just say, its easy, use this library and this method. I am not sure how difficult is this problem. Sorry. I know how to calculate it on paper, I just include last equations into every other equations, and I will get quadratic or more degree equation in the end and just solve it. But maybe there is better method which can be implemented in python for example.

Comment: I think you need to linearize these equations to solve for increments in { dC1, dC2, dC3, dX }.  Start with an initial guess and iterate your way to a solution using gradient descent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a system of **non-linear** equations.
For the example you provided, the system has four equations for four unknowns

[image]

where **u** is vector of unknowns C1, C2, C3, X, and **f** is vector function with components

[image]

You need to google for solvers of nonlinear systems of equations (e.g. nonlinear rootfinding problem). For python there is [scipy.optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#multidimensional), for example. Also, you may be interested to read chapters 4.5 and 4.6 of [Fundamentals of Numerical Computation](http://tobydriscoll.net/fnc-julia/nonlineqn/newtonsys.html) to understand choice of the solver.

Comment: You know, you need a hug for your help. Thank you very much for your time :) <3